# Neo4jClient Get nodes by label

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4jclient

i understand that we can use cypher parameters for querying. However can i apply to the type of nodes that i want to return? For example if there are more than one node type, i want to dynamically get the relevant nodes by passing the node label as the method argument.

For example:

```
public List<eventA> GetNodesByLabel(string labelName)
{
List<eventA>> list =
                    this.client.Cypher.Match("(event:label)")
                    .Set("label = {labelParam}")
                    .WithParam("labelParam", labelName)
                    .Return(event=> event.As<eventA>())
                    .Results;
return list;
}
```

I can't seem to get this approach to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the APOC procedure [apoc.create.addLabels](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) to add a dynamic label.

```
public List<eventA> GetNodesByLabel(string labelName)
{
List<eventA>> list =
    this.client.Cypher.Match("(event:label)")
    .Call("apoc.create.addLabels(event, [{labelParam}])").Yield("node")
    .WithParam("labelParam", labelName)
    .Return(event=> event.As<eventA>())
    .Results;
return list;
}
```

Comment: can i ask what does the command Yield does? what should be its arguments and why did you use "node" as its argument

Comment: `YIELD` is actually part of the `CALL` clause, and indicates the return value(s). The `node` identifier is really part of the signature of the `apoc.create.addLabels` procedure, and that identifier name must be used (but it can be renamed e.g., `YIELD node AS foo`).

Comment: it seems to work but my returned results is 0. Any advice?

Comment: i've edited it to `this.client.Cypher.Match("(event)")` but this will return me all nodes. i feel i'm close but something is still missing

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I've tried your method but i cant seem to get it right. I've used the `Query.DebugQueryText` to get the corresponding cypher text of this method and this was the output :
`MATCH (pEvent:label)
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(pEvent, ["SomeValidLabel"])
YIELD node
RETURN pEvent`

however running the cypher returns me 0 results even though there are nodes with this label

Comment: Ok i think what this query is actually it adds this Label Name to all nodes, and so the return result is 0. My initial question is what is the correct way using .Net Neo4jClient  to write the method in such a way i want to return nodes with a given label name